Flex 1st row 1 item, 2nd row 3 items
I'm trying to build out something with flex that has a layout like this...
  []
[][][]
[][][]

My breakpoints are fine when stacked (1 item per row), or 2 items per row by using
ul {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
    flex: 0 0 48%;
}

li:first-of-type {
    flex: 0 1 50%;
}

But once I get to 3 per line the first item doesn't seem to want to be by itself. I'm fine with having the flex code change with @media breaks, but I need to stay in flex as my last line needs to have any items below 3 centered aligned, not left aligned.
I've tried other combinations but have had no luck keeping the first line item the same size as the remaining row items.

One method is to use a grid and position the last/last-but-one items specifically.
This snippet uses a 6 column grid, each item taking up two column widths.
The first item always starts at column 3.
7 grids are shown here, ranging from 1 item to 7.


<style>
  .container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    gap: 5px;
  }
  
  .container>div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: var(--c);
    grid-column-end: span 2;
  }
  
  .container>div:first-child {
    grid-column-start: 3;
  }
  
  .container>div:nth-child(2) {
    grid-column-start: 1;
  }
  
  .container>div:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(3n) {
    grid-column-start: 4;
  }
  
  .container>div:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(3n+2) {
    grid-column-start: 3;
  }
  
  .container>div:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(3n+2) {
    grid-column-start: 2;
  }
  
  .container:nth-child(1) {
    --c: cyan;
  }
  
  .container:nth-child(2) {
    --c: magenta;
  }
  
  .container:nth-child(3) {
    --c: yellow;
  }
  
  .container:nth-child(4) {
    --c: black;
  }
  
  .container:nth-child(5) {
    --c: red;
  }
  
  .container:nth-child(6) {
    --c: green;
  }
  
  .container:nth-child(7) {
    --c: blue;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>




This is a great solution. My only question is there something I can do to the last row since the content will be dynamic? I'm unable to have the code be specific if the last row contains 1, 2 or 3 items. Because it's coming from Wordpress (ACF Repeater). But I see in your provided example the last row does have centered items which is great. I don't know if CSS contains a "if" type statement to say
if 1 item grid-column-start: 3
else 2 item grid-column start: 2
else 3 item grid-column-start: 1
Just to ensure the last row stays centered.

Hi, I don’t understand your question as the last row will adjust. Could you give an example of when there might be a problem with it?

I put together an example of what I am facing on Codepen.
https://codepen.io/nateads/pen/MWdEKXr
I just noticed in your code that the rows are containers. Because the content is dynamic by way of ACF Repeater I don't think I can put each item on a row without running into future issues as profiles change. Plus for mobile responsiveness I don't know how that would work when the column shrinks down to 2 items per row.

The rows are not in containers. In my snippet there are several examples, 1 item, 2 items etc. that is to show that the method works for anything from 1 to 7 items. Each is independent. It will work for any number of items.

If there is a requirement to have a solution for two columns not three please add that to your question. It can be simply done using a similar technique but it is an additional requirement which needs spelling out. In particular, at what viewport width do you need to go down to 2?

Sorry for my late reply, I just got back to this project today. I ended up solving my own problem while trying to make an example on codepen.
Hope this helps anyone else facing the same problem.
(Displays all the profiles in a single column)
ul { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 3rem 4%;
}

(Displays the profiles in 2 columns but keeps the first profile on it's own row centered)
@media screen and (min-width:450px) {
    ul {
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    ul li {
        flex: 0 0 48%;
    }
    ul li:first-of-type {
        flex: 0 0 100%;
    }
    ul li:first-of-type .profile-img {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto 1.5rem auto;
    }
}

768px + (Displays the profiles in 3 columns but keeps the first profile on it's own row and centered)
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    ul li:first-of-type .profile-img {
        width: 30%;
    }
}

